# How to iteratively design the view (HTML/CSS) in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm currently developing a webapp in spring boot with thymeleaf as templating engine. Im coming from the PHP/NodeJS(SailsJS)-World so iteratively designing html pages with css was never a problem. I could make some minor changes in the html/css code, go back to the browser and hit refresh to see the change.

I do this a lot in PHP/NodeJS. It's countless forward and backward until I get the design I was shooting for.

Now I want to do this in SpringBoot but whenever I change the HTML/CSS code (static or template) an refresh in the browser, there is no change. I have to restart the application to see the change and that needs at last 4 seconds and up to 14 seconds in some situations. That's completely unacceptable as I have to go back and forth so often that this would massively decrease my productivity but I wanted to use SpringBoot in the first place to increase my productivty.

I googled a bit and some people seem to advise the "Spring Devtools". I included this dependency but still no change. Even if it would work, it would just auto-restart the app which doesn't solve my problem. There must be a way to tell Spring not to cache my static and dynamic html content but to deploy/process them directly from their place within the project. I mean in other Frameworks like PHP-Zend or NodeJS-SailsJS this is the absolute standard.

In PHP-Zend for example there is a cache but it is disabled by default and should only be enabled for production environments by the developer. Is there a way to let Spring behave in similar manners?
And if not, how do Spring developers design their html/css efficiently?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is definitely possible to do, and Thymeleaf does have a [template cache](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#template-cache) (see linked documentation).  Without your configuration though, it's hard to give any specific help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Be warned**! The following solution is something you only want in your **LOCAL** application.properties. You do not want to add these lines to your QA, PROD, ... application.properties files.

In your **LOCAL** application.properties you need to add the following 3 lines

`spring.thymeleaf.cache=false`

`spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:./src/main/resources/templates/`

`spring.resources.static-locations=file:./src/main/resources/static/`

You will obviously need to adjust the paths to your folder structure and restart the server.